# How to search multiple fields in Firestore using Filter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a search feature in my Android app and am stuck with implementing it.

The app uses Firebase Firestore as a database. It has a collection called **questions** with lots of documents that use string fields **choice_a** and **choice_b**.

I want to query all documents IF the user query contains/starts with any word that is mentioned in choice_a or choice_b fields.

This code works when query only one field:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("questions")
    .where(Filter.or(
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.toLowerCase()),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1)),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1) + '\uf8ff')
            )
        )
    )
    .get();
```

But it doesn't work if use two fields like this:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("questions")
    .where(Filter.or(
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.toLowerCase()),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1)),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_a", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1) + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery.toLowerCase()),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
            ),
            Filter.and(
                    Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1)),
                    Filter.lessThanOrEqualTo("choice_b", textQuery.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + textQuery.substring(1) + '\uf8ff')
            )
        )
    )
    .get();
```

**Error:**

> All where filters with an inequality (notEqualTo, notIn, lessThan, lessThanOrEqualTo, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqualTo) must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'choice_a' and 'choice_b'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly isn't clear from the error message?

Comment: @AlexMamo I understand the error message. I am looking for suggestions on how to achieve what I'm trying to do without using paid services like Algolia.